# Using Get in a sentence

Tags: grammar

Which is the correct sentence and why?

> Grab this offer before it disappears

or

> Grab this offer before it **gets** disappeared.

Answer (score 3):

The sentence

> Grab this offer before it disappears.

plainly states that the offer could soon disappear without clarification of the possible mode of its disappearance.

> Grab this offer before it **gets** disappeared.

gives the impression that the offer could soon disappear, but not without an external help. That is, that someone will make the offer dissappear.

**Get** + **past participle** is used in informal speech to create passive structures instead of **be** + **past participle**:

> Don't speed up on this road, there are cameras all around, we will **get caught** (= **be caught**)

Here's a link to a BBC page explaining the uses of [get + past participle](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv138.shtml).

Comment: The transitive use of *disappear* most people are likely to be familiar with is relatively new (about fifty years old) and has a fairly specific meaning.  See http://english.stackexchange.com/q/111998/28567